# How can get the file directory that require my npm packages

Tags: node.js

I created a  npm package. In the function,I need to know whice file require my package. How can I do ?

sample:
this is my package.json

```js
{
  name: "path-judge",
  main: "lib/index.js"
}
```

```js
exports.doSomething = function(){
  //how can I get the file path that require this package.
  //....
}
```

if there is a file `test.js` require `path-judge`, like this:

```js
var judge = require("path-judge");

judge.doSomething();
```

in the index.js how can I get the test.js file path?

the test.js isn't the main function, other file require it.

for example: 

`node other.js`

other.js:

```js
test = require '../../test.js'

//...

console.log('....')
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#loading_from_the_require.paths_Folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`module.parent`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent). If that property exists, then it means the module is being loaded via `require()` and not `node mymodule.js` directly.

In this object is a `filename` property. So you can easily use [`path.dirname()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p) on this value to extract the directory portion to get the path to the script doing the `require()`. Example:

```
var path = require('path');
if (module.parent) {
  console.log(path.dirname(module.parent.filename));
}
```